# Excel: Calculating working hours between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function

**Summary:**

I know that the function `NETWORKDAYS` can be used to find the number of business **days** (=excluding weekends and holidays) between two dates. But what if I want to know the number of business **hours** between, say, yesterday 14:00 and today 10:00?

**--> I need a function `NETWORKINGHOURS`** which doesn't exist (Excel 2003). In essence, take `NETWORKDAYS` and add two additional parameters `start of working day` and `end of working day`. It sounds simple, but my attempts to create it by formula quickly become very complex.

**Question:**
How can I make my `networkhours` work even when the end time-of-day is before the start time-of-day?

**Details:**

I have an Excel sheet with two date+time columns. I want to calculate the number of days+hours+minutes between the timestamps, but only count business hours.

The function `NETWORKDAYS` can be used to find the working days excluding weekends and holidays (by subtracting 2 from its result, because the function counts both the start day and the end day regardless of time). So far so good. It looks like this ([inspiration from here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=72966#post72966)):

```
=CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS($A6;B6;holidays)-1
;"d "
;HOUR(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1)))
;":"
;IF(MINUTE(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1)))>9
;MINUTE(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1)))
;CONCATENATE("0";MINUTE(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1))))))
```

gives me very nice results in the format **`1d 2:30`** assuming that I have named cells for `startofday` (08:00), `endofday` (16:00) and `holidays` (column with date values).

This works very well **except that the formula breaks when the end time-of-day is before the start time-of-day.** Here are my test data and formulas:

[image]

networkdays-2 `=NETWORKDAYS($A6;B6;holidays)-2`
hours `=MIN($B$3;MOD(B6;1))-MAX($A$3;MOD(A6;1))`
minutes `=MINUTE(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1)))`
networkhours *see code block above*

Comment: Have you tried using `Tools -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula` on the formula that is failing?

Comment: `HOUR(MIN(endofday;MOD(B6;1))-MAX(startofday;MOD($A6;1)))` concerns me; Excel cannot interpret negative values as date/time values - I suspect this is the problem because the two times given (12:00 -> 11:30) result in a negative value of 30mins (-0.0208333..).

Comment: @DMA57361 yes it's the negative result that is the problem, but I'm at a loss for how to solve that.

Comment: Can you delay or remove the call to `HOURS()`? Dates are just stored as numbers under the hood (with a step of 1 being a day, so 1/24 is an hour, etc). If you keep them as numbers you can simply add them up, and then manually format the resulting field as date/time.

Comment: Could you use the absolute function to give you a psoitve number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whole working days = NETWORKDAYS - 2

time worked on first day = MAX(0, endofday - MAX(starttime, startofday))

time worked on last day = MAX(0, MIN(entime, endofday) - startofday)

total work days = whole working days + INT((time worked on first day + time worked on last day) / (endofday - startofday))

extra time (after total days) = MOD(time worked on first day + time worked on last day, endofday - startofday)

Comment: @torbengb: wait, what comment?

Comment: Oh, it has been moderated in the meantime. Please disregard!